# I created an object out of an other object but an attribute was modified in all of the arraylist

Tags: android, for-loop, kotlin, foreach

I need to cast an object from a data structure to an other but have got a problem doing this.

Every thing was working fine inside the for loop but when the loop is completed i don't know why the attribute picture is changed and duplicated in all the list, you can see this in the screenshot that i took and really i have no explanation how this could be like this and i am currently out of solutions, maybe someone here can help.

Thank you.

[This is the picture for the Log debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akPCk.png)

```
binding.updateItem.setOnClickListener {
                val itemsPending = arrayListOf<ItemToShipRequest>()
                val picturesRequest = ArrayList<PictureRequest>()
                shipment.items!!.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    picturesRequest.clear()
                    item.picture.forEach { picture ->
                        picturesRequest.add(PictureRequest(picture.pictureUrl))
                    }
                    val y = ItemToShipRequest(
                        item.titleItem,
                        item.quantityItem,
                        item.unitPrice,
                        item.unitWeight,
                        item.weightUnit,
                        item.category!!.id,
                        item.productLink,
                        picturesRequest,
                    )
                    itemsPending.add(y)
                    Log.e(TAG, "itemsPending $index: ${itemsPending[index]}")
                    Log.i(TAG, "================================================")
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "itemsPending OUTSIDE LOOP: $itemsPending")}
```

Comment: Well, what you're adding to your items is a reference to an `ArrayLists` whose contents you keep changing.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i just found a solution just by modifying the picturesRequest variable inside the forEach loop so it can be reinitialized every time with every iteration and it worked ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the same `picturesRequest` list to each `ItemToShipRequest` instance, so they are all sharing the same list. Since you clear the list and refill it for every item in your inner loop, they are all using a list that shows information corresponding to the last item in the list.

Avoid using ArrayList/MutableList when you don't need it. These sorts of errors are less likely when you work with read-only Lists.

The `map` function creates a read-only List out of the contents of another list, so it is a nice, concise way of transforming your data. And the `run` scope function lets you omit all the `item.` from within.

Your above code would become:

```
binding.updateItem.setOnClickListener {
    val itemsPending = shipment.items!!.map { item ->
        item.run {
            ItemToShipRequest(
                titleItem,
                quantityItem,
                unitPrice,
                unitWeight,
                weightUnit,
                category!!.id,
                productLink,
                picture.map { PictureRequest(it.pictureUrl) }
            )
        }
    }

    //...

}
```